# Deployment of Vlocity Insurance Product Configuration

Tags: deployment, attribute, vlocity, financial-services-cloud, product2

Is there any way from where we can deploy Vlocity Insurance Industry components like Vlocity Attributes Category, Vlocity Attributes, Child Products (Coverage Spec/Insured Party/Insured Item), root product, and eligibility rule together from one org to another org? or we have to create it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use one of those:

- [Salesforce IDX Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_idx_workbench_desktop_application.htm&type=5)
- [Vlocity Build](https://github.com/vlocityinc/vlocity_build#vlocity-dx-desktop-application)

Salesforce IDX Workbench is a desktop app that runs on Vlocity Build tool, which is a Command Line Interface. The basic deploys are performed via Salesforce IDX Workbench, where as the more complex one would be done via the Vlocity Build CLI tool.

Comment: I tried following this guide (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.psc_deploy_lwc_org.htm&type=5) and doesn't work at all. If you happen to know if it actually works do let me know. For now I will check your links

Comment: @compski The link you provided is specific to Public Sector Solutions. Are you using it?

Comment: Yes installing to Public Sector Solutions Trial Org (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.psc_create_trial_org.htm&type=5). Anyway I found they have an appexchange like way to deploy to prod/sandbox but it didnt work for me